# how to pivot simple table of 2 rows in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table

expected table is this:

```
good_days   bad_days
6           25
```

But I have this table:

```
day_type    x
bad_days    25
good_days   6
```

my code is not working:

```
select * 
from (select * from main_table)t
  pivot(count(x) for day_type in ('bad_days', 'good_days')  )  as pivot_table
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this

1. Use postgresql extension [tablefunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tablefunc.html) which contains `crosstab` method which can accept query result and pivot the result
2. You can also create a custom query (only works if you've less and known `day_type` column values)

```sql
WITH cte (day_type, x) AS (
        VALUES ('bad_days', 25), ('good_days', 6))
SELECT sum(good_days) AS good_days,
       sum(bad_days) AS bad_days
FROM (
          (SELECT x AS good_days,
                  0 AS bad_days
           FROM cte
           WHERE day_type = 'good_days')
      UNION ALL
          (SELECT 0 AS good_days,
                  x AS bad_days
           FROM cte
           WHERE day_type = 'bad_days')) AS foo
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(x) filter (where data_type = 'bad_days') as bad_days,
       sum(x) filter (where data_type = 'good_days') as good_days
from t;
```